# Using try-catch blocks for various exceptions (java)

Tags: java, try-catch

So I am trying to make a couple try-catch statements in my Postfix expression evaluator to catch exceptions that will come up from a input file. I just need help making those try-catch statements.

So the current output is:

```
5
2
1
8
-4
2
-4
Exception in thread "main" java.util.EmptyStackException
    at LinkedStack.pop(LinkedStack.java:44)
    at PostFix.postfixEvaluation(PostFix.java:171)
    at PostFix.readFromTheFile(PostFix.java:49)
    at PostFix.main(PostFix.java:21)
```

while I want it to output:

```
5
2
1
8
-4
2
-4
ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad character input: " "
ERROR: java.util.EmptyStackException for 1+1
ERROR: java.util.EmptyStackException for 11+*
ERROR: java.util.EmptyStackException for +11
ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad character input: "@"
```

The input file contains:

```
   511+93/2-932/-149657%/*-+14+96*5/7%-149-+6*57%/     1+111+*+1111@
```

Here is my current method for the code, the try-catch blocks would go here:

```
  public static Integer postfixEvaluation(String input){



      StackInterface<Integer> stack = new LinkedStack<Integer>();

      Integer result = new Integer(0);



      for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++){

         String characterNum = input.substring(i, i+1);

         Integer integer1 = new Integer(0);
         Integer integer2 = new Integer(0);






         if (characterNum.equals("0")) {
            Integer character = (Integer.valueOf(characterNum));
            stack.push(character);

         }
         else if (characterNum.equals("1")) {
            Integer character = (Integer.valueOf(characterNum));
            stack.push(character);

         }
         else if (characterNum.equals("2")) {
            Integer character = (Integer.valueOf(characterNum));
            stack.push(character);
         }
         else if (characterNum.equals("3")) {
            Integer character = (Integer.valueOf(characterNum));
            stack.push(character);
         }
         else if (characterNum.equals("4")) {
            Integer character = (Integer.valueOf(characterNum));
            stack.push(character);
         }
         else if (characterNum.equals("5")) {
            Integer character = (Integer.valueOf(characterNum));
            stack.push(character);
         }
         else if (characterNum.equals("6")) {
            Integer character = (Integer.valueOf(characterNum));
            stack.push(character);
         }
         else if (characterNum.equals("7")) {
            Integer character = (Integer.valueOf(characterNum));
            stack.push(character);
         }
         else if (characterNum.equals("8")) {
            Integer character = (Integer.valueOf(characterNum));
            stack.push(character);
         }
         else if (characterNum.equals("9")) {
            Integer character = (Integer.valueOf(characterNum));
            stack.push(character);
         }
         else if (characterNum.equals("*")) {
            integer2 = stack.pop();
            integer1 = stack.pop();


            result = integer1 * integer2;


            stack.push(result);



         }
         else if (characterNum.equals("/")) {
            integer2 = stack.pop();
            integer1 = stack.pop();

            result = integer1 / integer2;


            stack.push(result);

         }
         else if (characterNum.equals("%")) {
            integer2 = stack.pop();
            integer1 = stack.pop();


            result = integer1 % integer2;


            stack.push(result);
         }
         else if (characterNum.equals("+")) {
            integer2 = stack.pop();
            integer1 = stack.pop();


            result = integer1 + integer2;


            stack.push(result);

         }
         else if (characterNum.equals("-")) {
            integer2 = stack.pop();
            integer1 = stack.pop();

            result = integer1 - integer2;


            stack.push(result);

         }




      }
     return result;
   }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you get any character first check is character is blank if yes then through your custom exception.

```
if(characterNum.equals("")){
  throw new BadCharacterException(" Bad character input: \" \"");
}
```

Comment: Hm.. what about for the other 3 EmptyStackExceptions? I understand the BadCharacterExceptions now though!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, you wan't your exceptions grouped on the end of application. I think you can just catch your exceptions as normally (for example atish shimpi answare) and then in catch part handle the exception by pushing them to some sort of fifo collection. And after whole input processed just print it out.

I would chose checked exception here, and handle printing of exceptions in place where you are printing them. You can decide then if you like to stop, how to format message etc.